# Al mostrar datos con JavaScript no muestra el diseño

Tags: javascript, html5

tengo un problema con JavaScript.

Lo que pasa es que estoy trayendo unos datos con JavaScript que son unos testimoniales, pero los intento mostrara en un tipo Slider pero se me están mostrando en columna y no se están mostrando como aparece en la plantilla.

> Diseño de la plantilla

```html
<div class="testimonial3 spacer bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-info pull-right">Escribe Tu Testimonio</button>
        </div> -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="pull-right">
                    <button onclick="show_form();" type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-info pull-right">Escribe Tu Testimonio <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div><br>

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
                <span class="label label-success label-rounded">Testimonial 1</span>
                <h2 class="title">Mira lo que dicen nuestros clientes</h2>
                <h6 class="subtitle">La opinión de nuestros clientes es sumamente importante porque gracias a ellos la calidad de nuestros servicios a mejorado.</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Row  -->
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme testi3 m-t-40" id="list_testimonio">
            <!-- item -->
            <div class="item" data-aos="fade-right">
                <div class="card card-shadow">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h6 class="font-light m-b-30">“Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras venene veliel vestibulum.”</h6>
                        <div class="d-flex no-block align-items-center">
                            <span class="thumb-img"><img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/images/testimonial/1.jpg" alt="wrapkit" class="circle"/></span>
                            <div class="m-l-20">
                                <h6 class="m-b-0 customer">Michelle Anderson</h6>
                                <div class="font-10">
                                    <a href="#" class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- item -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Como se me está mostrando con JavaScript

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  show_testimonio();
});

function show_testimonio(){
    $.ajax({
        type  : 'ajax',
        url   : '<?php echo base_url('index.php/inicio_controller/list_testimonio')?>',
        async : true,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var html = '';
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){

                html += '<div class="item" data-aos="fade-right">'+
                    '<div class="card card-shadow">'+
                        '<div class="card-body">'+
                            '<h6 class="m-b-0 customer">'+data[i].titulo+'</h6>'+
                            '<h6 class="font-light m-b-30">“'+data[i].comentario+'”</h6>'+
                            '<div class="d-flex no-block align-items-center">'+
                                '<span class="thumb-img"><img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/images/testimonial/1.jpg" alt="wrapkit" class="circle"/></span>'+
                                '<div class="m-l-20">'+
                                    '<h6 class="m-b-0 customer">'+data[i].empresa+'</h6>'+
                                    '<div class="font-10">'+
                                        '<a href="#" class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>'+
                                        '<a href="#" class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>'+
                                        '<a href="#" class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>'+
                                        '<a href="#" class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>'+
                                        '<a href="#" class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            }
            $('#list_testimonio').html(html);
            
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('error');
            swal("Algo salió mal!", "Error al enviar tu testimonio!", "error");
        }

    });
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonial3 spacer bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-info pull-right">Escribe Tu Testimonio</button>
        </div> -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="pull-right">
                    <button onclick="show_form();" type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-info pull-right">Escribe Tu Testimonio <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div><br>

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
                <span class="label label-success label-rounded">Testimonial 1</span>
                <h2 class="title">Mira lo que dicen nuestros clientes</h2>
                <h6 class="subtitle">La opinión de nuestros clientes es sumamente importante porque gracias a ellos la calidad de nuestros servicios a mejorado.</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Row  -->
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme testi3 m-t-40" id="list_testimonio">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se me están mostrando en columna y no como viene en la plantilla.

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Gracias

Comment: Asegúrate que estés incluyendo las librerías JS y CSS al igual que las tiene la página en la que te estas basando. ¿Puedes compartir el enlace de ejemplo?

Comment: que esta ocurriendo primero ¿llenas los div? o ¿aplicas el slider?, por que debe ser en ese orden, llenar divs y hasta que termine aplicar el slider.

Comment: Si estoy poniendo los css y js

Comment: Tambien podrias agregar el HTML que se genera :) con "inpeccionar Codigo" de tu navegador de preferencia.

Comment: No se cual sea el orden, lo único que quise hacer fue traer los datos con JavaScript y mostrarlos pero no me quedo y le e estado batallando

Comment: intente llenar el div, para eso le coloque un id y después coloque las iteraciones que hice con JavaScript en el div con el id="list_testimonio" pero no se muestran como en la plantilla, se colocan en columna y asi no los necesito.